# Batch Converting SharePoint List XML Documents to PDF

Tags: 2010, document-library, infopath, pdf

I created a browser-enabled Infopath form as part of a project and ~350 forms were submitted to a Document Library. The forms are to be compiled and printed as a single book and I'm thinking that the easiest way to accomplish this is to figure out a way to batch convert the XML files from the exported Excel list to PDF files.

I've seen mentions of third-party solutions for exporting the forms as PDFs as they're being submitted for the first time, but haven't really seen any methods for handling completed forms.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Coding something yourself is not impossible, but it is extremely tricky as InfoPath tends to make things very difficult. Although I am biased - as I have worked on this solution - I would seriously consider an off-the-shelf solution that does all the hard work (batch converting / merging multiple files including InfoPath Forms) for you either using the SharePoint User Interface or Workflows (including Nintex, Visual Studio, SharePoint Designer).

Have a look at https://muhimbi.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/228089267-What-PDF-merging-facilities-are-available